# Find Z = max(X,Y) value of the distribution function at x = a.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I really strugger with this question.

> Two archers with probabilities p = 0.52 and q = 0.58 independantly of
>   each other shooting at the target. Both shot n=5 times. Let's say that first archer hitted X times while second archer hitter Y times. Find Z =
>   max(X,Y) value of the distribution function at x = a(a=2.51).

I don't understand how to calculate Z = max(X,Y) part.

Any help appreciate, thanks.

Comment: The problem doesn't even define $X$ and $Y$. Are you citing the original problem statement?

Comment: I've forgot to add one sentence. Now it's full question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compute the distribution function of $Z$ using the fact that 
$$
Z\leq z\iff X\leq z \; \text{and}\; Y\leq z
$$
In particular
$$
P(Z\leq z)=P(X\leq z) P(Y\leq z)
$$
by independence. We want
$$
P(Z\leq 2.51)=P(Z\leq 2)=P(X\leq 2) P(Y\leq 2)
$$
since $Z$ is integer valued. Since $X$ and $Y$ are binomially distributed the probabilities on the right hand side are easy to compute.